# How do I build xdebug with the correct php binaries

Tags: php, xdebug, bitnami

I'm running a sandboxed bitnami instance on php 7.1.2, and it didn't come with xdebug. No big deal I just download xdebug 2.5.1 and compile it myself. I followed the compilation instructions (https://xdebug.org/docs/install), I used the `phpize` binary that was shipped in my bitnami instance, and it gave me the correct result:

```
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20160303
Zend Module Api No:      20160303
Zend Extension Api No:   320160303
```

I followed with `./configure` and `make`, everything is fine, the `xdebug.so` extension is correctly built and I move it to my bitnami files and add it to my `php.ini`. The extension is not loaded and I get this error:

```
Xdebug requires Zend Engine API version 220121212.
The Zend Engine API version 320160303 which is installed, is newer.
```

`220121212` is the version that came with my OS, I'm guessing it's somewhere in `/usr/bin` or something. So even if I use the correct `phpize` binary, it still builds with the wrong version. How do I force it to build with the correct php binaries? (which are in my bitnami files)

```
> ~/bitnami/php/bin/phpize --version
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20160303
Zend Module Api No:      20160303
Zend Extension Api No:   320160303

> phpize --version
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20121113
Zend Module Api No:      20121212
Zend Extension Api No:   220121212
```

EDIT: I should specify that my OS is `OS X 10.10.5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it, I had to run `./configure` with the correct options as such:

`./configure --with-php-config=/Users/boux/bitnami/php/bin/php-config`